# Intellisense Plugin Options in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I can't find in VS 2012 or 2010 where you specify Resharper vs. using Visual studio's build in intellisense.

I installed R# as usual and I always use R# Jedi option.  But just curious where I can go back and change this if I ever need to through VS options.

Answer (score 1):

Go to tool in the menu bar, Import and Export Settings then select Reset all settings and Tools

Answer (score 0):

You can set the IntelliSense back to Visual Studio via Resharper->Options...

[image]